# Nested user defined functions using apply in R

Tags: r, for-loop, apply, lapply, sapply

How would the following be written using apply?

```
# Variables
age <- 1:100
Y   <- age+5
d   <- 0.25
dx  <- 5
a_x <- 1:dx
Yd  <- matrix( 0, nrow=max(age), ncol=dx )

# Nested loop is computationally inefficient?
for (a in age){
  for (ax in a_x){
    Yd[a,ax] <- (Y[[a]] * (1 - d) ** (ax-1))
  }
}
```

My model has a lot of these nested for loop structures, because I am incompetent. I am hoping to improve the computational time using apply. I find the apply functions rather confusing to get into. I am looking for a solution that illustrates how one can obtain such nested structures using apply. Hopefully, from there on I can apply (pun intended) the solution to even more complicated nested for loops (4-5 loops within each other).

For example

```
Ydi <- rep( list(), 6)

for (i in 1:6){
  Ydi[[i]] <- matrix( 0, nrow=max(age), ncol=dx )
}

# Nested loop is computationally inefficient?
for (i in 1:6){
  for (a in age){
    for (ax in a_x){
      Ydi[[i]][a,ax] <- (Y[[a]] * (1 - d) ** (ax-1)) + i
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: For the first nested loop, I would use matrix products instead of loops or `apply`s: `Y %*% t((1-d) ** (a_x-1))`.

Comment: For the second one, I think you should use arrays rather than a matrices in lists.

Comment: Also, your "for" loops are very clear and well written, so I wouldn't try to replace them with something that is possibly marginally faster too quickly.

Comment: Thank you for the comments and the kind words. I heard using for loops in such a way is not "R-like". The end goal is a stochastic evaluation of the model for which I need around 40,000 runs. Each run, using the for loop structure, takes around 10-15 min which makes this literally impossible. I tried multi-threading and improved input sampling designs but in essence nothing works and I need to improve the efficiency of each run. Rewriting everything in apply fashion is my last hope. I heard it is supposed to be quicker

Comment: Try using operations on matrices and arrays, then: it should be faster than loops (and `apply`s) and more intuitive to write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `expand.grid` instead:

```
df <- data.frame(expand.grid(a = age, ax = a_x))
df[['Yd']] <- (df[['a']] + 5) * (1 - d) ** (df[['ax']] - 1)
```

This is infinitely extendable (subject to memory constraints) - each additional nested loop will just be an additional variable in your `expand.grid` call. For example:

```
new_col <- 1:2
df_2 <- data.frame(expand.grid(a = age, ax = a_x, nc = new_col))
df_2[['Yd']] <- (df_2[['a']] + 5) * (1 - d) ** (df_2[['ax']] - 1) + df_2[['nc']]
```

This essentially switches to a [tidy data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidy_data) format, which is an easier way of storing multi-dimensional data.

For easier syntax, and faster speed, you can use the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
dt_3 <- data.table(expand.grid(a = age, ax = a_x, nc = new_col))
dt_3[ , Yd := (a + 5) * (1 - d) ** (ax - 1) + nc]
```